# start method of Activator of Eclipse Plugin is not called

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am making a plugin to provide Preference Page in Eclipse 4.x.

I followed this tutorial on [Vogella-Preferences](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html).

The problem with page is that after I enter values once, and then exit, and then reopen Preferences, values are not preserved. Possible cause of this can be PreferenceStore is not specified.

Following is code for Preference Page:

```java
import com.varun.preference.main.Activator;

public class EASEPreferences extends FieldEditorPreferencePage 
                implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

    public EASEPreferences(){
        super(GRID);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {

        setPreferenceStore(getPreferenceStore());
//      setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
        setDescription("Final Implementation");
    }

    @Override
    protected void createFieldEditors() {

        addField(new DirectoryFieldEditor("PATH", "Get &Default Keystore:",
                getFieldEditorParent()));

        addField(new BooleanFieldEditor("BOOLEAN_VALUE",
            "&Automatically run scripts that are not signed(Not Recommended)", 
            getFieldEditorParent()));
    }
}
```

Right now, code is working and preference page is visible but it is not getting saved.

If I uncomment the second line of init method and comment first, then error says

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at 
>   com.varun.preference.page_final.EASEPreferences.init(EASEPreferences.java:24)

Activator.java is as below

```java
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {

    public static Activator plugin;
    public static BundleContext context;

    public Activator() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context){

        Activator.context = context;
        System.out.println("---InStart---");
        plugin = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context){

        Activator.context = null;
    }

    public static Activator getDefault(){

        return plugin;
    }

}
```

Here, what I am presuming is *start* method is not called while running plugin since println statement is not getting printed.

Am I missing something with Activator?

My Manifest.mf file is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Final
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.varun.preference.page.final;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: VARUN
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime
Bundle-Activator: com.varun.preference.main.Activator
```

I am not using any product or feature. It is a simple plugin.

*Eclipse version: 4.5.2*

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is you haven't checked: *Activate this plug-in when one of its classes is loaded* in the `MANIFEST.MF` configuration. Checking that adds:

```
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

to your `MANIFEST.MF` and everything then works.

When you have `Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy` it means you don't have to explicitly start your bundle, which is a good thing. In Eclipse you want to do as much lazily as possible and starting a bundle is a great example of that.

Read more about [tracking lifecyles](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/23/how-to-track-lifecycle-changes-of-osgi-bundles/) or [starting them](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/06/10/osgi-and-start-levels/).

Comment: Also, if this flag is checked, make sure that you load some class from the plugin else you may get an bundle exception (not initialized) while stopping that plugin (Eclipse oxygen)

Comment: Also, if in product configuration (configuration - tab), if auto-start is enabled and still class is not loaded, you will get exception while stopping the plugin or rcp app. To correct, this recheck and uncheck the lazy start (in case if no classes from your plugin are used)